# Prefixing output text in batch

Tags: command-line, batch, wmi

I am trying to create a remote, WMI query script that will query a bunch of machines and tell me the MemoryChip configuration information. This way, we can find out what machines physically have 1 chip or 2 chips and how big each one is and find out who has a 1x4GB configuration and get them upgraded.
The base I am running is:
wmic /node:"[ComputerName]" MEMORYCHIP get BankLabel,DeviceLocator,Capacity,Tag > memory.txt

The problem is that this just kicks out the following, which provides no ability to reference the computer being queried:
BankLabel  Capacity    DeviceLocator  Tag
           4294967296  DIMM A         Physical Memory 0
           4294967296  DIMM B         Physical Memory 1

You run this 50x, and there's not a quick way to find out which machine has what. What I am trying to do is have the script Echo the "ComputerName" to the line preceding the text or append it at the next line.
All of my efforts to do this have not produced viable results, so I am hoping at least one person who still uses batch (for things, quite frankly, I should learn powershell to execute) can help me with this.

Comment: What are you passing to `/node` - a list of machine IDs or a single ID?

Comment: Right now, it is 1 machine per line. So each time we query a new machine, we start a new WMIC line.     

TL;DR - One machine per /Node switch

Comment: Ok, so why not echo each machine ID to the text file before redirecting WMIC's output to the same file?

Comment: @Karan I tried that. `echo ... > file` followed by `wmic ... >> file` sticks a load of `NUL`s in file. Example "[ComputerName] 
ÿþB a n k L a b e l ", etc where the spaces are `NUL`s. Hence my answer using `wmic` twice.

Comment: `echo` and `wmic` together redirecting to the same file seems to be a no no. Something to do with character sets maybe?

Comment: echo output is "ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators" and wmic output is "Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode text, with CRLF line terminators"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What I am trying to do is have the script `echo` the "ComputerName"

Try the following:

```
wmic /node:"[ComputerName]" OS get csname > memory.txt
wmic /node:"[ComputerName]" MEMORYCHIP get BankLabel,DeviceLocator,Capacity,Tag >> memory.txt
```

Output here (not including the `/node` option as I can't test it):

```
CSName
HAL
BankLabel  Capacity    DeviceLocator  Tag
Bank 0     4294967296  SODIMM1        Physical Memory 0
```

Where `HAL` is my computer name.

Comment: the "csname" works at getting the current machine's computer name, but I'm using the "/node:" switch to do a remote computer.
So basically, if I enter the "wmic OS get csname" above each line, it gives the same output each time it is run. Perhaps if I use the "/node" with the "WMIC OS" I'll get the remote machine as well...

Comment: Did the remote csname work as expected? If so I will update my answer.

Comment: So typing the following produces the closest to my desired result as I expect to get from batch:  
  
`wmic /node:"[ComputerName]" OS get csname > memory.txt inline code in backticks wmic /node:"ComputerName" MemoryChip get BankLabel, Capacity, MemoryType, TypeDetail, Speed >> memory.txt `

Answer (score 1):

Just use something like this:

```
@echo off
echo "ComputerName" >> Memory.txt
wmic /append:Memory.txt /node:"ComputerName" MemoryChip get BankLabel,DeviceLocator,Capacity,Tag
```

Comment: Sneaky way to get around the `echo` and `wmic` redirection problem. I will remember this one ;)